# Styles not inserted into HEAD using Webpack MiniCssExtractPlugin with Create React App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, webpack, create-react-app

I'm using create-react-app to create a component library using Storybook JS. The aim is to publish a NPM package where these components can be used in other projects. SASS is being used for this library, with global variables defined and imported into the `src/index.js` file.

I'm at the point of testing my NPM package, and trying to bundle it with Webpack V4. This has been semi-successful using `npm link` on another local project. However, I'm facing an issue with MiniCssExtractPlugin where the styles are not being inserted at all into the HEAD of this project.

The SASS stylesheets are converted into CSS and added to the `dist/` folder of my component library project with no issues. But these don't get applied anywhere when importing components via the NPM package to my other project, e.g. `import { Button } from '@my-account/components';`

There are no issues on my dev environment when using style-loader, and the styles are inserted straight into the DOM with a `<style>` tag. I'm sure I must be missing something, but I feel like I've exhausted everything to try diagnose this. Is create-react-app not compatible with this plugin? Or are styles not automatically injected to the HEAD of projects via NPM packages with this plugin?

The styling does work if I import the file from the NPM package into my local project, e.g. `import '@my-account/components/dist/main.cd2be00655e79c5077cb.css';` - but this doesn't seem maintainable if styles are regularly updated and the file uses a hash in its name?

I attempted to add HtmlWebpackPlugin to create an index.html file, but this didn't resolve the issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

webpack.config.prod.js

```
const path = require('path');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'production',
    devtool: 'source-map',
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve('dist'),
        filename: 'index.js',
        libraryTarget: 'commonjs2'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js?$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                use: 'babel-loader',
            }
        ],
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                sideEffects: true,
                use: [
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    {
                        loader: 'css-loader',
                        options: {
                            sourceMap: true
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'sass-loader',
                        options: {
                            sourceMap: true
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'sass-resources-loader',
                        options: {
                            resources: require(path.join(process.cwd(), 'src/assets/sass/WebpackStyles.js')),
                            hoistUseStatements: true
                        }
                    }
                ],
            },
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js'],
    },
    plugins: [
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: '[name].[hash].css'
        })
    ]
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Component libraries regularly require css to be imported alongside the js in order to work properly. If you update your plugins as:

```
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
        filename: '[name].css'
    })
```

Then you can instruct consumers of your library to add `import '@my-account/components/dist/main.css'` which is a little easier to swallow. I'm not sure there's a magical way to have the styles just show up without extensive custom webpack loaders in your consumers.

Comment: I thought this could be the case. I shall go with this for now as it does seem the most simple approach to take. Thanks for your help!